# I forgot about the linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $T:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ is a linear transformation and we are given $T\begin{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix}$ and $T\begin{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2\\2\\2\end{pmatrix}$. What is $T\begin{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2\\2\\2\end{pmatrix}\end{pmatrix}$?

This is my working:

(2,2,2)=2(1,0,0)+2(0,2,2)=2(1,2,3)+2(2,2,2)=(6,8,10)?

Am I correct?

Comment: I think so: T(2,2,2)=2T(1,0,0)+2T(0,1,1)=2(1,2,3)+2(2,2,2)=(6,8,10)

Answer (score 3):

You are not correct. I am missing several $T's$.

Correct is

$$T(2,2,2)=T(2(1,0,0)+2(0,1,1))=2(1,2,3)+2(2,2,2)=(6,8,10).$$

Answer (score 0):

It should be $$(2,2,2)=2(1,0,0)+2(0,1,1).$$
Can you end it now?

The final result  is right.

Comment: Can down-voter explain us, why did you do it?

Comment: I am not the down-voter, but the OP wrote $(2,2,2)=2(1,0,0)+2(0,2,2)=2(1,2,3)+2(2,2,2)=(6,8,10)$ which is not right.

Comment: @Fred Yes, of course. I wrote a right line. Also, the answer $(6,8,10)$ is right.